# Download Microsoft c++ compiler for windows without visual studio IDE

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a way to download somewhere Microsoft c++ compiler (msvc++) without having to install the full visual studio IDE ?

I have found some downloads from 2015 but there is no recent version.

Thanks

Comment: While Visual Studio Community is "free" (for some type of projects IIRC), the compiler and the environment really isn't. Also, while the compiler can be used stand-alone once installed, it's not possible to get it as a standalone package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022 are available for download.
You can find them on the [visual studio downloads site](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Just expand the "Tools for Visual Studio" chevron, and you'll find the build tools download.